# Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'RestClient' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, infobip, infobip-api

I am trying to integrate a bulk SMS API. After following their sample code, I am getting `Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'RestClient' is not defined.`

The code is as below

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug = "true" ContentType="text/html"       ResponseEncoding="iso-8859-1" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.net.mail"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.http" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="microsoft.http" %>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Restclient" %>

<SCRIPT language="vb" runat="server">


Sub Page_load(S as Object,E as EventArgs)


Dim client = New RestClient("https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/single")

' Dim byt As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strOriginal)  
'
'    ' convert the byte array to a Base64 string
'
'    strModified = Convert.ToBase64String(byt)

Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json")
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json")
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic   ctrtre2hvbGFkcm0xOmNoYW5nZW1lMUE=")'base64 of usename and password
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{""from"":""SMS"", ""to"":[  ""4356653443"",""2348056355307""],""text"":""Test SMS.""}", ParameterType.RequestBody)

Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
response.Write(response)




end sub
</SCRIPT>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Where should the definition of the type 'RestClient' be?

Comment: Where and how should the definition of the type 'Restclient' b' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've mentioned `RestClient` i'm going to assume you are trying to use the [RestSharp Project](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp). You'll need to add the runtime binary as a reference.

An easier option would be to add it via Nuget.

**UPDATE FOR ADD REFERENCE**

In Solution Explorer, double-click the My Project node for the project.

In the Project Designer, click the References tab.

Click the Add button to open the Add Reference dialog box.

In the Add Reference dialog box, look for "Browse" then locate the dll on the file system where you store it or navigate to the bin if you have it there.

Comment: Scartag, can you please give example or reflect it on the code

Comment: @Pope I can't reflect a binary reference in the code. You'll need to look for the dll check this url and unzip the most recent version and put the dll in your bin folder https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/downloads

Comment: Scartag, Thank you for your response. I have  unzipped the  library into my bin folder, but i am now getting "CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RestClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: <SCRIPT language="C#" runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var client = new RestClient("https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/single");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic wm07545nZW1");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"from\":\"InfoSMS\", \"to\":\"2348067231165\",\"text\":\"Test SMS.\"}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}

Comment: Scartag, Thank you. <%@ Import Namespace="RestSharp" %> worked

Comment: @Pope there should be a grey colored tick mark by the side of the answer. Close to where you have the upvote and downvote buttons. You can click it to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: please i need to change the "sender" and "238045366373" to varaible strings such that that can assume different values ata different times

request.AddParameter("application/json", "{""messages"":[{""from"":""sender"",""to"":[""238045366373""],""text"":""May the God be with you Jolaoluwa!""}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody)

Please help

Comment: @ scarTag please i need to change the "sender" and "238045366373" to varaible strings such that that can assume different values ata different times

request.AddParameter("application/json", "{""messages"":[{""from"":""sender"",""to"":[""238045366373""],""text"":""May the God be with you Jolaoluwa!""}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody), The error message i get is "
Compiler Error Message: BC30516: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddParameter' accepts this number of arguments."

Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764688/how-to-substitute-fixed-value-t-to-variable-name-into-request-addparameter-stat