# how to substitute fixed value t to variable name into request. addparameter statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, infobip

I need to change the `sender` and `238045366373` to variable strings such that that can assume different values ata different times

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{""messages"":[{""from"":""sender"",""to"":[""238045366373""],""text"":""May the God be with you Jolaoluwa!""}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody)
```

Comment: The error message i get is " Compiler Error Message: BC30516: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddParameter' accepts this number of arguments." Please help –

Comment: please past the code that is causing the issue ... the attempt at the variable strings.

Comment: request.AddParameter("application/json", "{""messages"":[{""from"":"&sender&",""to"":["&foneno&"],""text"":""May the God be with you Jolaoluwa!""}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody)

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending to only a single number you could use this function.

```
Private Function SendInfoBip(smsHeader As String, mobileNumber As String, message As String) As String

    Dim client = New WebClient()

    Dim message2 As String = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message.Trim())


    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.20404)")

    client.QueryString.Add("user", "YOUR_USERNAME") 'Replace YOUR_USERNAME with your actual username

    client.QueryString.Add("password", "YOUR_PASSWORD") 'Replace YOUR_PASSWORD with your actual password

    client.QueryString.Add("GSM", mobileNumber)

    client.QueryString.Add("SMSText", message2)

    client.QueryString.Add("sender", smsHeader)

    Dim baseurl As String = "http://api2.infobip.com/api/sendsms/plain"

    Dim s As String = client.DownloadString(baseurl)


    'Dim temp = s.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)



    'Dim flag As Boolean = Long.Parse(temp(0)) > 0

    'Return flag

    Return s

End Function
```

All you'll need to do is call `SendInfoBip` as shown below.

```
    Dim sender = "Scartag"
    Dim mobileNumber = "2348023061555"
    Dim message = "My brand new message"
    Dim result As Boolean = SendInfoBip(sender, mobileNumber, message)

    'result now holds the value you want to output to the screen
```

**UPDATE**

If you require the correct way of using variables instead of the hardcoded values as you requested early see below.

```
Dim header = "Sender"
Dim mobileNumber = "2348023061555"
Dim mobileNumber2 = "23480230619085"
Dim message = "Test message"

request.AddParameter("application/json", "{""messages"":[{""from"":""" + header + """,""to"":[""" + mobileNumber + """, """ + mobileNumber2 + """ ],""text"":""" + message + """}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody)
```

Comment: I ave been able to successfully send messages to single and  fixed numbers, but the issue arose when i am sending to multiple numbers  and variable  numbers, so i need to represent the numbers, sender and message as variable

Comment: yes, i tot as much but i was surprised when i changed the fixed number to a variable name and the code came up with an error

Comment: yes, Thank you. I got "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Source Error: 


Line 58:     Dim baseurl As String = "https://api2.bulksms.com/apisms/1/text/single"
Line 59: 
Line 60:     Dim s As String = client.DownloadString(baseurl)
Line 61: 
Line 62:

Comment: no, that is not what i am using on the code, i just typed it i the question

Comment: But why cant we just  use the below script as provided by infobip on their website and substitute fixed valued with variables string as in the below statement 

request.AddParameter("application/json", "{""from"":""infoSMS"", ""to"":[""2348055558307"",""2348022265313""],""text"":""Test SMS.""}", ParameterType.RequestBody)

Comment: i got this response BadRequest{"requestError":{"serviceException":{"messageId":"BAD_REQUEST","text":"Bad request"}}}

Comment: @Pope i think i made the mistake of using the one you pasted here in the comments .. instead of the one originally in the question .. will make the changes now.

Comment: copied and pasted, will keep trying

Comment: @Pope Glad to help :)

Comment: please if i decided to use the 1st code you sent using Dim baseurl As String = "http://api2.infobip.com/api/sendsms/plain", how will i capture the response as a string and display it of the screen

Comment: @Pope You can change the return type of the method to return string instead of boolean and remove the boolean test at the end of the method and return the value "s" instead. i can modify it to reflect that if you want.

Comment: please do, to be very sure. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865052/why-do-i-get-error-message-when-i-loop