# Why do i get error message when i loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
' the loop statement 
do while messagessent < messages submitted 
    messagessent = messagesent + 1
    Dim client  = New RestClient("https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/multi")

    foneno = trim(foneno.Replace(",",""","""))

    Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json")
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json")
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic NutrtryoYW5nZW1lMUE=") 'base64   of usename and password
    request.AddParameter("application/json","{""messages"":[{""from"":""" +  senderid + """,""to"":["""& mobileno &""" ],""text"":""" + message + """}]}",ParameterType.RequestBody)

    Dim eresponse As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
loop
```

Comment: i don't see any loop here. Could you post the entire code please?

Comment: OMG, and whats that error you get?

Comment: I edited the formatting so that the loop is now visible.

Comment: "messages submitted" is a valid variable? does vb accept spaces in variable names these days?

Comment: What error are you encountering?  I don't believe this would actually compile, given the "messages submitted" issue that scartag has pointed out.

Comment: The variable names are consistent in the script I only made alteration when posting the question. The script actually worked. it sends the messages everytime is is executed. the only challenge is it responds with {"requestError":{"serviceException":{"messageId":"BAD_REQUEST","text":"Bad request"}}} if the loop is executed else it gets the correct response message

Comment: messages submitted is not the actual variable name used. just use that for clearity

Comment: Could you please edit the question so that the code is the thing you actually compile & run? This way we could only guess why you get BAD_REQUEST response from server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what other issues the code has but from what i can see here you have two obvious errors.

1. The loop conditional statement uses a variable `messages submitted` i doubt this is valid.
2. You are processing a variable `foneno` and using a different one in the code below it `mobileno`. obviously one of these 2 haven't been declared.

Comment: The variable names are consistent in the actual script. i only made alteration to to variable name when posting the question . The script actually worked. it sends the messages everytime is is executed. the only challenge is it responds with {"requestError":{"serviceException":{"messageId":"BAD_REQUEST","text":"Bad request"}}} if the loop is executed else it gets the correct response message

Comment: messages  submitted is not the actual variable name used. just use that for clearity

Comment: @Pope always best to post the actual code .. that's what will bring clarity .. without the actual code, no one can tell whats wrong.